# passport.js return error/failureFlasg message to view

Tags: express, passport.js

I just started with express and passport.js and am having a difficulty with showing error messages during authentication with passport

When user successfully authenticate I am able to redirect the user and all is well, however, if the same email is authenticated with a different strategy I would like to show a message saying that the given email is already associated with a different strategy.

Here's my auth-routes.js

```js
router.get(
    '/google', 
    passport.authenticate('google', {scope: ['email', 'profile']})
);

router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google', { successRedirect: '/protected/'}));
```

Here's my authController.js

```js
passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            callbackURL: cbUrl,
            clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_KEY,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET
        },
        (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => verify(profile, done, 'Google')
    )
);

function verify(profile, done, provider) {
    User.findOne({
        email: profile.email || profile.emails[0].value
    }).then((currentUser) => {
        if (currentUser) {
            if (currentUser.provider !== provider) 
                return done(null, false, {message: `Login with ${provider} failed, this account is already associated with ${currentUser.provider}` });
            else 
                return done(null, currentUser);
        } else {
            new User({
                name: profile.displayName,
                email: profile.email || profile.emails[0].value,
                userId: profile.id,
                provider: provider
            }).save().then((newUser) => {
                return done(null, newUser);
            });
        }
        return done('Something went wrong!');
    });
  }
```

to sum it up, if I registered an account with email jhon.doe@gmail.com using Google oauth and later try to sign in or sign up with jhon.doe@gmail.com but this time using Facebook oauth, I would like to return a message and display that message on my login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after some reading I found my solution, in case anyone else also have the same issue, here's the solution.

Install these dependencies

```js
npm install express-session express-flash
```

Where you initialized the passport

```js
app.use(flash());
app.use(
    session({
        secret: process.env.SESSION_KEY,
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false
    })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

On my login.ejs

```js
<% if (messages.error) { %>
    <%= messages.error %>
<% } %>
```

My auth-routes.js

```js
router.get(
    '/facebook/redirect', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { 
        successRedirect: '/protected/', 
        failureRedirect: '/auth/login' ,
        failureFlash: true
    })
);
```

And finally, my authController.js

```js
done(null, false, { message: `Login with ${provider} failed, this email  is already associated with ${currentUser.provider}` });
```